# get select value/default value from dropdownlist into JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I'm trying to display a table using ag-grid that has pagination options. I have a drop down list with the number of rows that I want to display per page.

My question is how do I get the value from the drop down list (default value when the page is loading or selected value) and use it in my ag-grid code?

```
<div>
        Display:
        <select class="dropdwn">
            <option value="10" selected>10</option>
            <option value="50" >50</option>
            <option value="100">100</option>
            <option value="500">500</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

jQuery function that gets a value from the dropdown list:

```
$( ".dropdwn" )
  .change(function() {
    var str = "";
    $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
      str = $( this ).text() ;
    });
    x=window.parseInt(str);
```

These are the gridOptions from ag-grid:

```
var gridOptions = {
        columnDefs: columnDefs,
        rowData: rowData,
        pagination: true,
        paginationPageSize:x,
        rowModelType: 'pagination'
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

add `onchange` and `id`

```
    <select class="dropdwn" onchange="GetSelectedTextValue(this)" id="MyDropdown">
        <option value="10" selected>10</option>
        <option value="50" >50</option>
        <option value="100">100</option>
        <option value="500">500</option>
    </select>
```

and the function

```
function GetSelectedTextValue(ddlFruits) {
    var selectedText = MyDropdown.options[MyDropdown.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
    var selectedValue = MyDropdown.value;
    alert("Selected Text: " + selectedText + " Value: " + selectedValue);
}
```